# How do I create a button with the same visual appearance as the Google Play sign in button`?

Tags: android

I want to style my sign out button so it looks like the Google Play Service sign in button. Anyone have an ide how I can style a button like the screenshot below. Im using the standard google play sign in button. What Im after is a red (#dd4b39) button with an custom icon, a separator and a white text in the right size and padding. Anyone got a example how to do this?

[image: google play sign in button]

Comment: This isnt exactly a programming question... You need an imaging tool like gimp, inkscape, photoshop to do that.

Comment: Look at the source markup in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the nine patch image I found on this page, https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines and used them as a background drawable on a regular button.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it.

> 1st is to get it done through the web designer and apply the back
>   round png to the button
>
> 2nd is to use 2 buttons and align them side by side and on first
>   button write text g+ and on second button write Whatever text you want
>   and apply red background color to both